# load data from server-side in bootstrap data-table

Tags: php, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Hi i am new to bootstrap and angularJS. I am trying to load data from Server-Side mysql using PHP to bootstrap but its taking lots of time because there is 3000 records and the records are first loading then its showing in Bootstrap Data-Table which is taking more than 5mins. But i need to make it very fast. I am using AngularJS also.
On Google search i found out that we can do it by processing data in Server-Side. Hence, 
**i need to know how to populate data from server-side in Bootstrap Data-Table.**

Please Help Me !!! :)

**Sample JSON Data : (which i am getting from my PHP File)**

> get.php?json=all&query=SELECT * FROM `student` LIMIT 0,3

```
    [
       {
          "id":"1",
          "fname":"AARYA",
          "mname":null,
          "lname":"M",
          "gender":"MALE",
          "dob":"2004-10-04",
          "admissiondate":"2014-03-28 06:38:49",
          "academic_year":"2013-2014",
          "admissionnumber":"-",
          "class":"4",
          "section":"D",
          "rollno":"1",
          "applicationnumber":null,
          "mobile":"9655093949",
          "transporttype":"school-transport",
          "transportm":null,
          "pickuppoint":"ECHAMPATTI",
          "photo":"upload\/student\/1.jpg",
          "parentid":"1",
          "pickup":"125",
          "discountid":"1",
          "tf_discountid":"0",
          "bs_discountid":"0"
       },
       {
          "id":"2",
          "fname":"ABHI",
          "mname":null,
          "lname":"S",
          "gender":"MALE",
          "dob":"2004-06-13",
          "admissiondate":"2014-03-28 03:17:35",
          "academic_year":"2013-2014",
          "admissionnumber":"-",
          "class":"4",
          "section":"D",
          "rollno":"2",
          "applicationnumber":null,
          "mobile":"-",
          "transporttype":"own-transport",
          "transportm":null,
          "pickuppoint":"NA",
          "photo":"upload\/student\/2.jpg",
          "parentid":"2",
          "pickup":null,
          "discountid":null,
          "tf_discountid":"0",
          "bs_discountid":"0"
       },
       {
          "id":"3",
          "fname":"AHRAF",
          "mname":null,
          "lname":"A",
          "gender":"MALE",
          "dob":"2004-10-25",
          "admissiondate":"2014-03-28 03:17:35",
          "academic_year":"2013-2014",
          "admissionnumber":"-",
          "class":"4",
          "section":"D",
          "rollno":"3",
          "applicationnumber":null,
          "mobile":"9025509301",
          "transporttype":"school-transport",
          "transportm":null,
          "pickuppoint":"RAYAKOTTAI",
          "photo":"upload\/student\/3.jpg",
          "parentid":"3",
          "pickup":"1",
          "discountid":null,
          "tf_discountid":"0",
          "bs_discountid":"0"
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) with the data from your server within the table itself. Something along the lines of the following:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in serverData">
        <td>{{data.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{data.lname}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know about ng-repeat but does it will work as serverside and load data fast ?